# i want to disable templateCache functionality in gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-templatecache

I am using gulp for one of my angular project. I want to know how can i disable the templateCache thing in gulp. I tried commenting some code in build.js but that didn't work. here is the code in build.js.

```
    gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
  ])
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'tuktukV2Dahboard',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe($.rev())
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
  });
```

Comment: if you are using `gulp-angular-templatecache` then comment ` .pipe(templateCache())` line of code.  If still you are facing issue then let us know the code of gulp file.

Comment: It got installed by default. Here are the codes where templateCache is mentioned.

Comment: @MohanSingh Please check the code

Comment: Simple remove `.pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'tuktukV2Dahboard',
      root: 'app'
    }))` this code.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work